# Duplicate default active directory entries with new Azure account

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I've just created a new Azure account and I see there are *two* Default Directory active directory entries.

Anyone seen this before or know of a way to remove one of the entries? I'm pretty sure the account should be initialised with only one default directory.

[image: Duplicate Azure Active Directory entries]

Comment: I don't know why you have duplicate default AD but AFAIK there's no way to remove an existing AD in azure. I had created an AD with wrong name and what I can do is to create another one.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure Active Directories once created cannot be REMOVED, but they can be renamed as stated here http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/11/08/creating-and-managing-multiple-windows-azure-active-directories.aspx. Possible option for you would be to rename one as junk use the other, while Azure team comes up with updates for deleting WAAD.

Comment: Yes, I realise they can be renamed. Strange though that a new Azure account was created with two default AD entries. Just a strange bug I suppose.